# Set and read a cookie

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm using ajax to post data to a controller. In this controller I would like to set a cookie - I am then trying to read the set cookie (for testing purposes).

```
\Cookie::make('test', 'test-value', 2);
var_dump(\Request::cookie('test'));
die();
```

But the above results in a null value. Where am I going wrong?

Also on a side note - is it possible to store an array of values in a cookie. Is there any limit on the size of the array?

Comment: FYI, laravel has a method which does your var_dump and die for you so you could do `dd($value)` instead

Answer (score 2):

`\Cookie::make()` doesn't send the cookie to the browser of the user.
It just **creates** the cookie.

If you want to set a cookie, use `$response->withCookie(cookie('name', 'value', $minutes));`. (For more information, look here: http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/requests#cookies)

Also calling `\Request::cookie()` after setting a new one will not display the new cookie because the new cookie wasn't send with the last request.